# Tomcat 8 - Connection pool configuration

Tags: java, connection-pooling, tomcat8, tomcat-dbcp

I'm currently migrating an app from Tomcat 7. I've gone through the [migration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html) and updated the properties that have been changed in Tomcat 8 (DBCP 2). However, on starting the app, the following error is displayed. Does anyone know if the property **description** has been replaced with a new name? I could not find any documentation for this.

```
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = MyApp-Pool Ignoring unknown property: value of "MyApp Pool DataSource" for "description" property
```

Configuration:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyApp-Pool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" description="MyApp Pool DataSource"
              username="testuser" password="test" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"....... />           
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like, as part of [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBCP-435) issue, new log statements have been added to inform the user about properties that are not required. In my case, the property "description" is not used by DBCP (it has never been used in the first place) - so it can be removed from the configuration.